# Cannot send push notification from Parse dashboard

Tags: push-notification, parse-platform, push

I've created a parse Application, created provision for the phone that includes push notifications ,and created a p12 file and uploaded it to the Parse server so that the server can theoretically send push notifications. I can see the deviceToken get registered in the data browser, but when I try to use the Dashboard to send a push notification to all the devices, I get the following message "Query Builder inaccessible because no valid devices were found". Am I missing something? I've tried to poor through the documentation to figure it out but I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0):

In the data browser, do you have items in your Installation class? What does your query look like on the Parse Push Dashboard?

If you don't have any items in your Installation class, you're going to need to, on the devices, register for push notifications. I'm not sure if you're using iOS or Android, but for iOS, this looks a little like this:

```
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
```

and I'm doing this in my App Delegate's

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions;
```

method. On Android, I'm sure there is something similar.

In addition to this, if you're not querying over Installation objects, then that could be causing the issue too, because Push notifications have to be based off of Installations.

Comment: so it appears that it is registering with the installation table correctly. However, when I try to use the web interface to send a push notification it shows me an error "Query Builder inaccessible because no valid devices were found!" I'm not sure if this is my error or a bug in the web interface

Comment: So you have successfully registered a device for push?

Comment: Yes I have registered the devices and also gotten the certs uploaded